# "Unsupported osfamily: Linux" when trying to install Apache using Puppet

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, puppet, amazon-linux, facter

I'm trying to setup a simple Puppet setup on AWS EC2 using the latest Amazon Linux AMI.

I've followed through the install guide for [RHEL](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_el.html) and have a `puppetmasterd` daemon running.

When apply the following manifest in `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`:

```
node 'ip-172-31-1-239.eu-west-1.compute.internal' {
  class { 'apache': }
}
```

I get the error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-239 ~]$ sudo puppet agent --test
info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/concat/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Class['apache::version']: Unsupported osfamily: Linux at /etc/puppet/modules/apache/manifests/version.pp:37 on node ip-172-31-1-239.eu-west-1.compute.internal
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

From [`version.pp`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/manifests/version.pp#L13) of the Apache module for Puppet I can see why the manifest is failing to install Apache, but I can't understand why Facter is reporting the `osfamily` as "Linux" in the first place:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-239 ~]$ facter | grep osfamily
osfamily => Linux

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-239 ~]$ rpm -qa | grep facter
facter-1.6.18-7.25.amzn1.noarch

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-239 ~]$ rpm -qa | grep puppet
puppetlabs-release-6-11.noarch
puppet-2.7.25-1.4.amzn1.noarch
puppet-server-2.7.25-1.4.amzn1.noarch

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-239 ~]$ sudo puppet module list
/etc/puppet/modules
├── puppetlabs-apache (v1.4.0)
├── puppetlabs-concat (v1.2.0)
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.5.1)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

Anyone any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Amazon Linux. The [Puppet Labs Apache module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache) is not compatible with Amazon Linux. You will need to use one of the distributions which it is compatible with, or create your own Puppet module.

Comment: This isn't really a solution is it?

Comment: That is not entirely correct. `The module contains support for other distributions and operating systems, such as FreeBSD, Gentoo and Amazon Linux, but is not formally tested on those and regressions can occur.` ([source](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/#general)).

Comment: @MasterRoot24 After you get some experience with Amazon Linux and learn exactly what a steaming pile of trainwreck it is, you will wish you had switched.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Don't get me wrong: That was one of the first questions I asked when I started; "Why are you using Amazon Linux and not CentOS??" but this just gives me more ammunition to move our servers to CentOS :D

Answer (score 3):

After looking at it with a fresh pair of eyes today, I've found that Facter v1.7.0 includes a fix that classifies Amazon Linux as "RedHat" correctly: https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/commit/c12d3b6c557df695a7b2b009da099f6a93c7bd31

Now I know why it's being incorrectly reported, I need to know why I'm not getting Facter v1.7.0 installed from the PuppetLabs Yum repo, which is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the file `/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/facter/osfamily.rb`

which ends up using the osoperatingsystem as osfamily in the case of Amazon Linux.

Line 19 is:

```
 when "RedHat", "Fedora", "CentOS", "Scientific", "SLC", "Ascendos", "CloudLinux", "PSBM", "OracleLinux", "OVS", "OEL"
```

and should be:

```
 when "RedHat", "Fedora", "CentOS", "Scientific", "SLC", "Ascendos", "CloudLinux", "PSBM", "OracleLinux", "OVS", "OEL", "Amazon"
```

Comment: The joys of using magic strings, instead of capability detection.